# How do I create a tag on Stack Overflow without having required reputations to create one?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

I want to create a tag called "pyez" on Stack Overflow, but I do not have required reputations to create one. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Post this question on Meta Stack Overflow (rather than here), and make a good case for *why* the tag should be created. Users with higher rep might be willing to add the tag to an existing question to which it is applicable.